# .NET: recommended video tutorial for LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Can you recommend a ***single*** downloadable video (***one that you have actually watched*** and that you think is of high quality) introducing LINQ (not to be 
confused with "LINQ to SQL") to a somewhat experienced VB.NET/C# developer?

It could be a screen-cast showing real code.

"Downloadable" includes YouTube and ShowMeDo (Flash video) 
as there are ways to do this. A streaming-only video is not 
acceptable.

Comment: Let's close that - should never have been here (as in: Recommendation for a specific ressource and as such off topic per site rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anders Hejlsberg gave a couple great introductory talks about LINQ at the Lang.NET Symposium in [2006](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/4/1/94138e2a-d9dc-435a-9240-bcd985bf5bd7/AndersH-LINQ_0001.wmv) and [2008](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/e/5/ce5434ca-4f54-42b1-81ea-7f5a72f3b1dd/1-01%20-%20CSharp3%20-%20Anders%20Hejlsberg.wmv).

Answer (score 6):

Check out [LINQ Videos](http://www.asp.net/linq/videos) (www.asp.net).

Comment: Which video do you recommend?

Comment: It has many videos.You may feel it useful according to your current skillset.

Comment: This link is not working

Comment: it looks like microsoft removed the page when the redesigned it.check scottgu's tutorial. its not video. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/14/Using-LINQ-with-ASP.NET-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx

Comment: pls leave a comment when you downvote

Answer (score 2):

There is a few on [dimecasts](http://www.dimecasts.net/)

Comment: http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/Linq

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Tekpub Mastering Linq series](http://tekpub.com/production/linq) quite nice. It does cost a few bucks, but it's quite in depth.

Comment: Tekpub has been bought out by Pluralsight (per the link aboves error message).  Might want to remove this answer now that it is dead.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/

He has LINQ tutorials. His tutorials are great. I was a member for a year. It's $60 a year.

Comment: Can you recommend one in particular?

Comment: You get access to all the 500+ videos after subscribing. I subscribed for a year and watched many of the videos. I think a year is more than enough time to watch them.